# Systemd reload service from package install

Tags: systemd, sles

I am building an RPM (SLES12) package that installs a service with some software. The package dumps a new file into /etc/rsyslog.d to handle logging.

I would like to have the rpm basically run a "systemctl restart rsyslog" from the install... I guess from %post

Is there any specific way this should get run (like a macro) or should I just literally put that line in the scriptlet?